# How can I use the Google Calendar API in Java EE in Netbeans

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, netbeans-8, java-ee-7

I am currently working on a piece of university coursework where we are building a website using Java EE and Glassfish. We need to do some scheduling using a calendar API. We are not allowed to use any Java frameworks, everything we do must be done in JavaScript, which means that Gradle and Maven are a no go.

What I have tried so far:

1. I have created a project in Google's Developer site and have obtained by Client ID and Secret
2. I have downloaded the .jar files to use with our application from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download).
3. I have read through the README file and have imported the .jar files needed for both Java Core and Java Servlets
4. When I try and import the necessary package (`import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;`), I get a warning in Netbeans saying that the package does not exist.

Please can someone help me with this issue,

Thanks in advance.